# Need to achieve UI Like this

Tags: swift

I have been working on creating this UI.But not able to achieve that upper slant, I tried tweaking around my Code,
By Doing that, UI messes up.
Any Help would be appreciated.

```
 let buttonSlotRadius = CGFloat(50)
 let path = UIBezierPath()
 path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.layer.frame.width - buttonSlotRadius , y: 0))
 path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.layer.frame.width - buttonSlotRadius, y: buttonSlotRadius), radius: buttonSlotRadius, startAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: buttonSlotRadius, y: 2 * buttonSlotRadius))
 path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:  buttonSlotRadius, y: 2 * buttonSlotRadius), radius: buttonSlotRadius, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.layer.frame.width, y: 50))
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.layer.frame.width, y: self.layer.frame.height))
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.layer.frame.height))
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 2 * buttonSlotRadius))
 path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.layer.frame.width - buttonSlotRadius, y:  0))
 path.close()
 UIColor.white.setFill()
 path.fill()
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured It Out.
I added one more layer to Fix that

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.bounds.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: 50))

    path.close()
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    path.fill()
```

And Now its Working.[Working UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7QDy.png)